# Detect incoming connections to application

Tags: c#, rest, mono, tcplistener

I have an application with RESTful services, and when bad requests arrive, the application completely blows up. (On Mono, Windows just returns a Bad Request - which is the behavior I'd expect).

The application runs perfectly fine and is stable, performant - and was until we got a new customer for the application, which sends hundreds of requests per day, and every so often, I receive a request with no content-type header - which is the only way I've been able to reproduce this fault (sending a "broken" request).

I'm capable of logging when this fatal exception occurs, via the CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event. So I receive the following information:

```
[09:48] [Trace]
{
  "ClassName": "System.ArgumentNullException",
  "Message": "Value cannot be null.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke (object,intptr)\n  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) <Module>:end_invoke_bool__this___RequestContext&_IAsyncResult (System.Ser$
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2147467261,
  "Source": null,
  "ParamName": "contentType"
}
```

What I'm attempting to do, is log all connections to the app. I've found a TCP Listener, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something event-driven, where an event is fired every time a connection comes in.

Somewhat like this:

```
ConnectionListener conListener = new ConnectionListener;
conListener.ConnectionIncoming += IncomingConnection;

func IncomingConnection(Connection conn):
     if conn.Headers["Content-Type"] is null then
         conn.Block(400, "Content-Type missing!")
         Error("Received faulty request!")
         Error(ToJson(conn))
     end
end
```

Is there something similar to what I'm looking for?  I sadly can't simply switch to Windows, where everything is hunky-dory, so I somehow need to be able to intercept these connections and only if they contain bad data/are missing headers deny the connection or something similar.

Comment: Which web framework do you use? Which web server? If that is nginx for example - you can reject request based on header value. Apache can do this too I suppose. By the way - you better move to .NET Core whenever possible, because mono will give you this surprises again and again (does for me for several years already).

Comment: I'm not using any web frameworks, this is a console application which exposes a RESTful service interface. I'm using a ServiceContract with OperationContracts and WebGets/WebInvokes

Comment: So this console application is not behind nginx\apache and just accepts requests from outside world?

Comment: Only from internal sources, it restricts the listen IP to local IP addresses only. But essentially, yes.

Comment: Well if you don't find other solution provided by WCF (as I understand you use WCF) - then you can consider to still host it behind nginx, it has many benefits (though for internal applications - less so). Ultimately, if your application is not very big in terms of code - best solution is to move to asp.net core.

Comment: Sadly that's not an option, either. I have to somehow solve this problem without major changes to the application as such.

Comment: Well application as such will not change at all. It will listen to some local port on loopback interface and nginx will listen on your current endpoint and proxy all to your application.

Comment: Do you have an example for this?

Comment: It's called "reverse proxy", so you can find a lot of information about this by googling "nginx reverse proxy".

Comment: I'll check it out. Cheers a bunch

Comment: Quick update: Just as I was implementing the reverse proxy, I was given a green light to switch to Windows. Wonderful, now to move a solid 2.5TiB of archived data.